# Capturing video & storing on hard disk in .3gp format (fmj)

Tags: java, webcam, fmj

I want to develop a java application to capture video from a usb web cam and store in .3gp format onto the hard disk.

Please provide me working code (if any) that stores the video in .3gp format.please help me friends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to grab each frame from camera and then apply the coding associated with 3gp format. See this, http://www.mediasoftpro.com/aspnet-3gp-encoder.html

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the web-images from your camera already, you can use [Xuggler](http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler) to encode them into a 3gp file in whatever codecs you want.

Comment: Thank you for reply.Can you help me out with the coding part?i am new to java.please!